# regex: put sentence into paragraph tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

hi I have a lot of sentences I want convert them into paragraphs (split sentences by dot). How can I make it with regex?

sample:

```
"MBB Industries AG: Veröffentlichung gemäß § 26 Abs. 1 WpHG mit dem Ziel der europaweiten Verbreitung MBB Industries AG 09.07.2014 16:48 Veröffentlichung einer Stimmrechtsmitteilung, übermittelt durch die DGAP - ein Unternehmen der EQS Group AG. Für den Inhalt der Mitteilung ist der Emittent verantwortlich."
```

I want this (there is a date inside - pay attention):

```
<p>MBB Industries AG: Veröffentlichung gemäß § 26 Abs.</p><p>1 WpHG mit dem Ziel der europaweiten Verbreitung MBB Industries AG 09.07.2014 16:48 Veröffentlichung einer Stimmrechtsmitteilung, übermittelt durch die DGAP - ein Unternehmen der EQS Group AG.</p><p>Für den Inhalt der Mitteilung ist der Emittent verantwortlich.</p>
```

I am able to make this with php use explode -> foreach -> add `<p>` tags.

but I want be able make it with regex. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the middle,

```
Replace: (\.[ ]+)
With: </p><p>
```

Then for the beginning:

```
Replace: ^"
With: <p>
```

And the end:

```
Replace: "$
With: </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$str = "MBB Industries AG: Veröffentlichung gemäß § 26 Abs. 1 WpHG mit dem Ziel der europaweiten Verbreitung MBB Industries AG 09.07.2014 16:48 Veröffentlichung einer Stimmrechtsmitteilung, übermittelt durch die DGAP - ein Unternehmen der EQS Group AG. Für den Inhalt der Mitteilung ist der Emittent verantwortlich.";
$str = '<p>' . preg_replace('/(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)/', '.</p><p>', $str) . '</p>';
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
<p>MBB Industries AG: Veröffentlichung gemäß § 26 Abs.</p><p> 1 WpHG mit dem Ziel der europaweiten Verbreitung MBB Industries AG 09.07.2014 16:48 Veröffentlichung einer Stimmrechtsmitteilung, übermittelt durch die DGAP - ein Unternehmen der EQS Group AG.</p><p> Für den Inhalt der Mitteilung ist der Emittent verantwortlich.</p><p></p>
```